# Why doesn't my wheel spin?

Tags: rear-wheel

————————— PROBLEM —————————

I just replaced my flat inner tube. All went good as normal. But when I put the wheel back to its place, it doesn't spin at all: [spin locked]

So the brake side of the wheel doesn't go to its original spot (you can see the gray circle at the start).  I think that is the problem because when I try to spin the wheel without the stick inside the wheel: [spin unlocked](https://vimeo.com/720348151)

I don't know how to explain this any better, but I can provide more visual material.

————————— SOLUTION —————————

Inside the brake caliper was a lot of junk. I cleaned it out with Q-tips and after that wheel went in as normal.

[image]
[image]

————————— NOTES —————————

I also noticed that my pad is pretty worn out so might think about buying a new one.

[image]

I also took another spring from my other bike.

Big thanks for everyone!

Comment: It looks like you've sprayed oil or something on the axle and brake disc, which would be a bad idea

Comment: I suspect you didn't install/tighten the quick release correctly.  Make sure the springs are installed correctly, then with quick release loose and the bike resting on the wheel (so don't put the bike upside down), tighten the quick release with medium strength.  Err on the side of too loose to check if this is the reason.

Comment: Swifty - yeah my dad put some stuff in the hole so it would like slide in its spot, but didn’t help

Comment: Superman.Lopez - thanks! Im gonna try that later if I understood correctly

Comment: Nice details on your solution, especially with the pictures showing the issues in detail. Now keep a watch on those areas in the future to keep them cleaned out and functioning well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second video, it seems that the frequency of the "jumping" could match the wave pattern of your brake rotor.
It seems to me that your brake rotor is not between the brake pads, but sitting on the side of one of the brake pads. Or you might have some dirt or foreign object in between your brake pads.
I would suggest taking the wheel out, checking your brake caliper and your brake pads. make sure everything looks clean (enough).
Note: Don't touch the rotor with bare fngers, and don't touch the brake pads with bare fingers: Fat or grease will make your brakes squeal.
If everything looks clean and free, re-insert your wheel, making extra sure the brake rotor slides between the brake pads.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that too. Sounds like that could work

Answer (score 2):

In the first video it looks like your wheel wasn't fully seated in the dropouts when you tightened the quick release.  This would put the wheel in the wrong position and make it likely either the disc rotor or the tyre is rubbing on some part of the frame or brake calliper.  I usually apply a little pressure on the wheel just before I fasten up the quick release to make sure both sides are fully seated in the dropout.

I'm not sure what's going on in the second video, maybe someone else has an answer to that.  I've never seen an axle moving around like that.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Thats what i thought at first. But its not the case, it simply wont go any deeper. Trust me even my dad tried. Thank you though!

Comment: Putting the QR spring(s) on the wrong way round will cause this, as they block the dropout

Comment: Swifty - i have a spring on the other side

Comment: @Harjuuso there should be springs on both sides

Comment: @AndyP uhmm im pretty sure i’ve never had more than one. Im gonna find another for the other side then